# R: How to create a df with columns of random strings

Tags: r, function, dataframe, random, repeat

I have a df, I would like one of the colums to contain a string of 5 random values between 1 and 100:

```
expected_df <- data.frame("x" = stri_rand_strings(4, 8), "y" = round(runif(4, 13, 272)), z =(c('2 3 50 17 9', '10 3 5 100 22', '86 30 74 10 27', '6 33 4 19 66')))
```

I have tried to create a function that repeat '1-100' 5 times, however it repeats the same 5 numbers for each row in the df

```
rand_str<- function() {
  x = c(sample(1:100, 5, replace = FALSE))
  return(paste0(x,collapse = " "))
}

df <- data.frame("x" = stri_rand_strings(4, 8), "y" = round(runif(4, 13, 272)), z =rep(rand_str(),4))
```

I have tried to add rep(rand_str(),4), however it doesn't solve the problem.

How can I create 4 rows with 5 different digits in each?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
rand_str <- function(n) {
  returnvalue <- c()
  for (i in 1:n) {
    x = c(sample(1:100, 5, replace = FALSE))
    returnvalue <- c(returnvalue, paste0(x, collapse = " "))
  }
  returnvalue
}
df <- data.frame("x" = stri_rand_strings(4, 8), "y" = round(runif(4, 13, 272)), z =rand_str(4))
```

Comment: While this works, this isn't the best way to use loops in R. I've included a couple of alternatives to consider in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The function you're looking for is `replicate`. With `replicate`, you can use your original `rand_str()` function like this:

```
replicate(4, rand_str())
```

Alternatively, you can rewrite your `rand_str()` function like this:

```
rand_str <- function(n) replicate(n, paste(sample(100, 5, FALSE), collapse=" "))
```

Demo:

```
set.seed(1) # So you can replicate these results
rand_str(4)
# [1] "27 37 57 89 20" "90 94 65 62 6"  "21 18 68 38 74" "50 72 98 37 75"
```

---

For reference, if you are going to use a `for` loop, either of the following approaches would perform more efficiently than Steffen's answer, which grows a vector with each iteration of the loop. In R, you should pre-allocate space to store the results of your loops. When possible, specifying the storage mode (for example, specifying when a `character` or `integer` is expected in the results) will help improve the function's efficiency.

This option creates an empty character vector of the required length before the loop, and each iteration of the loop replaces the empty vector at the given position with the pasted result of the sample.

```
rand_str <- function(n) {
  returnvalue <- character(n)
  for (i in 1:n) {
    returnvalue[i] <- paste0(sample(1:100, 5, replace = FALSE), collapse = " ")
  }
  returnvalue
}
```

This option creates an empty matrix where each row stores the results of the samples. Once the matrix has been filled, it gets `paste`d together using the `do.call(paste, ...)` idiom commonly used to paste together rows of a `data.frame`.

```
rand_str <- function(n) {
  m <- matrix(NA_integer_, ncol = 5, nrow = n)
  for (i in seq.int(n)) {
    m[i, ] <- sample(100, 5, FALSE)
  }
  do.call(paste, data.frame(m))
}
```